# How to get several processes to "chat" together?

Tags: bash, named-pipes

I am trying to simulate a 2-players game in bash. More precisely, there should be one central program (the game engine) and two player programs. The game engine should send the game info to player1, then get player1's output, then send the game info to player2, then get player2's output, and repeat.

If at all possible, I'd prefer the game engine not to be in charge of dispatching its outputs, and instead rely on a bash script to schedule the whole thing.

After reading stuff about named pipes, I figured that they were exactly what I needed, and came up with the following setup:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "rm -f $in1 $in2 $out1 $out2 $in $out; kill $pid; kill $pid1; kill $pid2" KILL

in1=/tmp/testpipe_in1
in2=/tmp/testpipe_in2
out1=/tmp/testpipe_out1
out2=/tmp/testpipe_out2
in=/tmp/testpipe_in
out=/tmp/testpipe_out

for p in $in1 $in2 $out1 $out2 $in $out; do
    [[ -p $p ]] || mkfifo $p
done

echo 0 > $in
./center.sh < $in > $out &
pid=$!
./player1.sh < $in1 > $out2 &
pid1=$!
./player2.sh < $in2 > $out2 &
pid2=$!

i=0
while true; do
    i=$((i+1))
    echo "Round $i" >&2
    cat < $out > $in1
    cat < $out1 > $in
    cat < $out > $in2
    cat < $out2 > $in
done
```

I'm testing this with the following game and players:

`center.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    sleep 2
    read i
    echo "Center : $i $((i+2))" >&2
    echo $((i+2))
done
```

`player1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    sleep 1
    read i
    echo "Player1 : $i $((i-1))" >&2
    echo $((i-1))
done
```

`player2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    sleep 1
    read i
    echo "Player2 : $i $((i+1))" >&2
    echo $((i+1))
done
```

I expected it to output something like

```
Center : 0 2
Round 1
Player1 : 2 1
Center : 1 3
Player2 : 3 4
Center : 4 6
Round 2
Player1 : 6 5
...
```

... but of course it doesn't work.

Instead, I get:

```
Round 1
Center : 0 2
Center :  2
Center :  2
...
```

Is the problem something obvious in my players? Or what is the correct way to setup this kind of dispatch of inputs/outputs?

Comment: I'd suggest using lock files.

Comment: @User112638726 Lock files seem to be intended to solve a different problem, what would you suggest that I lock?

Comment: Hint: KILL signal cant be trapped. If you need to clean something on exit, use `trap doSomething EXIT` .  "EXIT" is a built-in BASH pseudo-signal that combines all other signals except KILL which leads to finish of the script execution.

Comment: @drvtiny Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some changes that may get you further on:

- there's a typo in your 1st script. It should be:

  ```
  ./player1.sh < $in1 > $out1 &
  ```

i.e. out1 not out2.

- move the `echo 0 > $in` to after starting the players.
- change the final `while` loop to:

  ```
    while true; do
        i=$((i+1))
        echo "Round $i" >&2
        read <&5; echo "$REPLY" >&6
        read <&7; echo "$REPLY" >&8
        read <&5; echo "$REPLY" >&9
        read <&4; echo "$REPLY" >&8
    done 5<$out 6>$in1 7<$out1 8>$in 9>$in2 4<$out2
  ```

---

Initially the reader of a fifo is blocked until a writer writes into
the fifo. Once the writer closes the fifo, the reader reads eof but is
no longer blocked so continues to read eof until the writer re-opens
the fifo and writes again.
You would need to check the return code of `read` and re-open the fifo
as the reader in order to block again.

You can see this easily with:

```
while sleep 1; do read;echo "$? $REPLY";done  <testpipe_out1 &
sleep 5
echo hi >testpipe_out1
```

The read will block until the "hi", then loop with return code "1".

Comment: Indeed it seems to work! I was under the impression that putting the echo before or after the players would not change anything, since it would not echo until some would be there to listen, isn't it correct? Or is this change only needed with the new while loop? I guess that the change from cat to read;echo is needed because cat does not wait for the pipe to be non-empty before continuing? But I still don't understand why the loop works only with file descriptors aliasing the pipes...

Comment: The `echo` blocked the script on my system. Perhaps it was ok on yours. `cat` will only stop on eof which you'll never get. Putting the files outside the loop means they are only opened once.

Comment: Yes, I do get that, but why does the script fail if the pipes are opened/closed more than once?

Comment: I added to the answer an explanation of the problem I see.